# Space $C^1$ is finite dimensional in $C[a,b]$. What is its basis?

Tags: real-analysis

To prove that, I considered the identity mapping $J$ and since unit ball in $C^1$ is compact in space $C$,, then it has finite dimension. But I have no idea how to find a finite basis of this space.

Comment: The terminology is not properly set, compact/precompact/relatively compact/bicompact is not an issue: if needed, we consider closure. The paradoxical observation is that the compactness of unit ball implies finite dimension but it is clearly infinite dimensional...

Comment: See edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C^1$ is the space of continuously differentiable functions?  It definitely is not finite dimensional.  (For instance, the functions $1, x, x^2, x^3, \dots$ are all in $C^1$ and are linearly independent.)

The issue is that you're asking about compactness in a different topology.  The theorem is that if $X$ is a vector space with a norm, such that the unit ball *of that norm* (or any set containing the ball) is compact in the topology induced *by that same norm*, then the space is finite dimensional.  Here you are asking about compactness with respect to another norm.  The $C$-closure of the $C^1$-ball is not compact in the $C^1$ norm, and it doesn't contain a ball of the $C$-norm.  So there's no contradiction.